# Singular subject with plural objects

Tags: definite-article, subject-verb-agreement, singular-vs-plural

How to correct these sentences:

> Working class *is* the people who...

or

> Working class *are* the people who...

Comment: You need an article... **The** working class.

Comment: I would suggest that you avoid the dilemma by always using "the working classes" instead of "the working class." This would not have seemed unusual in the past since the working class was itself stratified (at least in the UK). This is not so much the case today, but it makes for a linguistic convenience.

Comment: @Mick thanks. The above sentences were just examples. How about a sentence like this: `This group of people are those`  or `This group of people is those`? I tend to avoid to be verbs in such sentence, but sometimes I need it, I feel awkward.

Comment: *Be* is intransitive, and the complements it takes are not objects.

Answer (score 5):

In your specific example

> The working class *are* people who...

"working class" is a collective noun, however you are referring to the individuals in the group ("who"), so a plural verb is appropriate

> The working class **is** *(a group of)* people...

refers to the group as a whole and so a singular verb is appropriate

[here](http://blog.dictionary.com/collective-nouns/)

Comment: This is actually more common in BrE than AmE.  In American English we don't usually make collective nouns plural, even when referring to the individuals.  So Americans would say, "the working class *is* ..," regardless of context.  See [this article](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2011/09/agreement-over-collective-nouns/) for more info.  Not always, though -- for example "the police" **are** plural on both sides of the Atlantic.

Comment: Agreed. Cambridge dictionary states that you can use it with either a singular or a plural verb. http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/working-class